# assign a variable from a file and compare with integer in Unix

Tags: bash

i have only one character to read from a file in UNIX. When i assign the file to a variable and compare with integer it gives integer error.

count.txt contains numeric character.
Below is the code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
_count=/apps/count.txt
_value=20
if [ _value -ge _count ] then
echo "Value is greater"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: The file contains only one character

Comment: you're not reading a file. It should be something like _count=$(cat /apps/count.txt)

Answer (score 1):

```
_count=$( cat /apps/count.txt )
_value=20
if [ $_value -ge $_count ]; then
    echo "Value is greater"
fi
exit 0
```

You can access the value in count.txt with "cat" and assign it to the variable. You also forgot to add a ";" after the if statement.

Comment: Thanks **Script** is running without semicolon

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use `cat`! Also you can use `(( ))` for arithmetical operations:

```
count=$( < count.txt)
value=20

if (( value >= count )); then
    echo "Value is greater"
fi
exit 0
```